# Detect if duplicate rules are enabled on an object

Tags: duplicate-management, datacloud, findduplicates

I've noticed that `theDatacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates()` method will not return gracefully if there are no active duplicate rules for the object.  Instead, it throws an exception

> System.HandledException: No active duplicate rules are defined for the
>   Contact object type

Has anyone else run into this?  What's the purpose of the `success` property on the `FindDuplicatesResult` class if the method throws an exception when it fails?  There's no way to detect if there are any active rules on an object?

Here's the code I use to test:

```
Contact con1 = new Contact(FirstName = 'Already', LastName = 'Exists', Email = 'already@exists.com');
List<Contact> cons = new List<Contact>{con1};
List<Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult> results = Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates(cons);
```

Comment: I believe we can only use this method when we have active duplicate rules associated with the input sObjects. And also I don't see methods to check if there are active rules on an sObject either.

Comment: Yep same behavior here

Answer (score 3):

Late response to the question, but ran into this issue myself and figured I'd post my workaround:

```
public static Boolean doDuplicateRulesExist(List<SObject> listOfSObjects){
    Boolean duplicateRulesFound = true;

    try {
        Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates(listOfSObjects);
    } catch(System.HandledException e){
        if(e.getMessage().startsWith('No active duplicate rules are defined for the')){
            duplicateRulesFound = false;
        }
    }

    return duplicateRulesFound;
}
```

Note that if your list of SObjects is mixed it will not tell you which SObject Type in your list of SObjects is problematic - this wasn't a requirement for me.